# Android 13 (API 33) introduces changes to advertising ID

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-console

I have not externally added com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID to my manifest file , but i use facebook and google libraries which uses AD_ID permission in their respective manifest files. So in this case , which section of functionality should i choose from the options when i select Yes as an answer to whether your app uses advertising ID.?[image]

Need Help for the same